# IntelliJ IDEA giving null pointer exception while starting the debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, nullpointerexception, build.gradle, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I am trying to start the debugger session in my IntelliJ it start giving the following error, throwing pull pointer I am not sure if any configuration need to be changed as it was working fine a week back.

Is there any plugin is needed Extra or cache clean is required?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what the error there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
It turns out somehow I had included jacoco code coverage when debugging.
Under edit (run/debug) configurations, look and see if you have included classes for coverage. If something is checked, uncheck it and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).